# Using MKLocalSearchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

`MKLocalSearchRequest` requires a natural language query to get local places (e.g. "Coffee").

Is there a way to get it to return a list of all places within the specified region?

Alternatively is there an API that does this?

Or will I need to make multiple requests ("coffee", "bar", etc.) and include a search function the user can use if we haven't retrieved the place they're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using MKLocalSearchCompleter its better and it reacts to user input rather than plain queries like coffee / bar plus it will take region to limit your search area as well.

Here is the link to documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearchCompleter_class/